# How to pass a parameter that could be any one of a bunch of similar objects?

Tags: java, interface

Let's take an example where I have two classes, "Triangle" and "Parallelogram", and an interface "Side".
The "Triangle" class has just 3 variables - a, b, and c, which store its end-points. Same for the "Rectangle", except there's a, b, c, and d.

Now, I want to pass a "Side" as a parameter into a "Plane" class, which needs 3 points, and makes a plane based on them.
How do I go about this, as I can't just use side.a, as the compiler isn't sure "Side" has the variable a.

Additionally, slightly unrelated, but how could I identify if a "Side" is actually a "Triangle" or a "Parallelogram"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question. But I guess you have something like this:

```
class Triangle implements Side {
    private Point a, b, c;

    // getters for a, b, c...
}

class Parallelogram implements Side {
    private Point a, b, c, d;

    // getters for a, b, c, d...
}

interface Side {
    // you don't know what to write here
}

class Plane {
    public void someMethod(Side side) {
        // this method needs at least 3 points, but if more points are
        // present, say 5, work with 5 points.
    }
}
```

I hope I understood you correctly. So I guess you just need to complete the `Side` interface.

If I were you, I would write it like this:

```
interface Side {
    Point[] getEndPoints();
}
```

You can implement it in your triangle and parallelogram classes like this:

```
class Triangle implements Side {
    private Point a, b, c;

    // getters for a, b, c...

    public Point[] getEndPoints() { return new Point[] {a, b, c}; }
}

class Parallelogram implements Side {
    private Point a, b, c, d;

    // getters for a, b, c, d...

    public Point[] getEndPoints() { return new Point[] {a, b, c, d}; }
}
```

To check whether there are three points, just do

```
  if (side.getEndPoints().length >= 3)
```

To check whether the parameter is a triangle, do this:

```
  if (side instanceof Triangle)
```

EDIT:

You said that you want `Side` to be empty and whatever that implements guarantees that the fields `a`, `b` and `c` exists and is public.

Here is a solution using reflection.

```
// in the method in the Plane class
Class<? extends Side> clazz = side.getClass();
Field aField = clazz.getField("a");
Field bField = clazz.getField("b");
Field cField = clazz.getField("c");

// getting the values of the fields
Point aPoint = (Point)aField.get(side);
Point bPoint = (Point)bField.get(side);
Point cPoint = (Point)cField.get(side);
```

Note that you also need to either add a really long `throws` clause or use try catch to catch all the exceptions that this might throw. Because of this, this approach is not recommended.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty accurate, sorry for not being clearer. And honestly the most likeable out of the answers so far, but isn't it possible to do this without a Getter?

Comment: I think you can do this with reflection (not exactly sure though) but it would waste a lot of time because reflection is slow. And interfaces are supposed to be used this way, so why not use it? @Torn

Comment: Yeah, sure, I suppose this answers my question, even though it's not the answer I was hoping for. Thank you.

Comment: @Torn I will try to come up with a solution using reflection, just for completeness.

Comment: "// this method needs at least 3 points, but if more points are
        // present, say 5, work with 5 points." Nightmare if any of those 5 points aren't in the same plane. How to detect the offender? Which of the 5 to trust as telling the 'true plane'? Even 3 points don't always determine a plane - what if they are on the same line? But anyway... some may actually enjoy nightmares, who am I to object?

Answer (score 0):

Your interface should be designed to provide the necessary information to the code that uses it. In the example you provided, a more useful interface that these classes could implement might be something called Shape that has two methods: getNumberOfPoints and getPoint. You could use this information to distinguish between shapes (or not distinguish between them, since maybe the exact shape shouldn't matter, just the shape data).

Comment: Can't I just have an interface without methods that guarantees that the points a, b, c exist?

Comment: No, but your interface may have methods `getA()`, `getB()` and `getC()` and thus guarantee that points a, b and c can be obtained through them. That’s as good, isn’t it?

Comment: Is it noticeably slower if I have to do this as many times per second as possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it from outside (it's harder but not impossible), however since the definition of a `Side`/`PolyhedronFace` has the plane as an intrinsic property, it's much better to ask the subclasses to report this plane themselves.

```
interface Side {
  // This method should return false if the face is not a valid 
  // planar figure (more than 3 points not all coplanar
  // or a degenerate case: 3 points on the same line or coincidental).
  public boolean isValid();

  // this method will return the supporting plane if isValid
  // otherwise throws 'InvalidStateException`
  public Plane3d getPlaneDef();
}

public class PolygonalFace
implements Side {
  // Store your set of points defining the Face here
  protected List<Point3d> vertices;

  // constructor and other methods here

  static protected Plane3d computePlaneIfOk(List<Point3d> vertices) {
    // implement here the magic to compute the plane definition 
    // if there is one or return null if there isn't one
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid() {
    return (null!=PolygonalFace.computePlaneIfOk(this.vertices));
  }

  @Override
  public Plane3d getPlaneDef() {
    Plane3d ret=PolygonalFace.computePlaneIfOk(this.vertices);
    if(null==ret) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, and let me guess, if I wanted points a, b, c from Side, I should implement methods getA, getB, getC, and I can't really use something like side.a?

Comment: @Tom rather than getA etc, better `getVertexList() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.vertices); }`